# Open Email(Outlook) with Attachment using Angular on a button click

Tags: c#, .net, angular, angular7, html-email

I have a client side application which uses Angular 7 for frontend and C# for backend.

Requirement : On click of a button in UI, let's say "open Mail with Attachment", i should open an email in outlook with an excel attachment in that mail that's opened.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot do this from the front-end.

If you use Office 365, you can integrate in an iframe Outlook and open a message there.

Answer (score 0):

You can request that the browser opens the associated email program and start a new email with the to filled in and a subject:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again">Send mail!</a>
```

or a message to multiple people with a subject and text body.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?cc=someoneelse@example.com&bcc=andsomeoneelse@example.com&subject=Summer%20Party&body=You%20are%20invited%20to%20a%20big%20summer%20party!">Send mail!</a>
```

But I don't think you can create a new email with an attachment.